# Append and Prepend in slice 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to get multiple `StreamSlice` in 3D and have a little confusion getting there.  I would like slices in the *xy* plane, *yz* plane and *xz* plane.  I would also like the ability to pick any plane. I am getting two plane slices, but when I try to get into the other plane I am unable to do so.  Also, I am not sure what `Append` and `Prepend` do in the `Arrow` function.  At first I thought it was appending lines, but if I change the code to `Prepend[#,1]` it shifts the plane over. The following is similar to my code:

```
ft[x_, y_, z_] := {y, -x, z}


gr1 = Graphics3D[(First@
  StreamPlot[ft[x, y, 0][[{1, 2}]], {x, -3, 0}, {y, -3, 3}]) /. 
  Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[Line[Append[#, 0] & /@ pts]]];
gr2 = Graphics3D[(First@
  StreamPlot[ft[0, y, z][[{1, 3}]], {y, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 3}]) /. 
  Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[Line[Prepend[#, 0] & /@ pts]]];
gr3 = Graphics3D[(First@
  StreamPlot[ft[x, 0, z][[{2, 3}]], {x, -3, 0}, {z, 0, 3}]) /. 
  Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[Line[Prepend[#, 0] & /@ pts]]];

Show[gr1, gr2, gr3]
```

[image]

I think from the code you can see what I am trying to get at.  I want the last graph `gr3` to be in the *xz* plane.

Answer (score 1):

```
gr3 = Graphics3D[(First @ StreamPlot[ft[x, 0, z][[{2, 3}]], {x, -3, 0}, {z, 0, 3}]) /. 
    Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[Insert[#, 0, 2] & /@ pts]];

Show[gr1, gr2, gr3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, use `Arrow[Riffle[#, 0] & /@ pts]` instead of `Arrow[Insert[#, 0, 2] & /@ pts]]`.